# Firebase functions - How to get logs grouped by call / request like for app-engine logs?

Tags: firebase, logging, google-cloud-functions

With app-engine, [java logs are grouped by request call like this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8110568/159943300-72abe505-2cef-45b8-ae1f-9fc56e6845f2.mp4).

But with firebase functions, each log create a new entry in the cloud logs.
Even with `import 'firebase-functions/lib/logger/compat'`, logs are better formatted but not grouped by function call like with app-engine.

How can I get grouped logs by firebase-function call?
Can `@google-cloud/logging` help?

Comment: Can't you just use the "trace" query term to filter a specific group of log entries in GCP Logs Explorer?

Comment: I can, but it's not as convenient as when it's already grouped. Currently, entries are mixed like spagheties, and I have to find and open the one with the error log, and then click to get all related entries by trace-id. When grouped, I can see at first sight the errors, and in one simple click, I get all the flow of the request. It's perfect.

Comment: Could you please make an example of the gouped log of GAE? My services on GAE have the same structure, creating an entry for each log operation; maybe you are using some sort of framework which wraps the log call, appending it into a structure that is persisted to GCP only oce the reply is sent to the client?